React native application jest coverage issue
I am running react native application. we are using jenkins dynamic agents to perform all the stages in job. i got one react native image from dockerhub and that supports for application dependencies. Using that image, i am trying to run
npm install
npm run test:ci
this test:ci contains below script under package.json
"test:ci": "jest --ci --runInBand --coverage || true"
Not only we tried more scripts, but pipeline is unable to get the coverage i am getting error like
**Aborted(dumped) **
i tried to debug this with diff diff npm commands sometimes after few test cases it getting Killed
sometimes it proceed with next sonar stage without generating the coverage folder its not ran all test cases
i tried the below scripts
{"test:ci": "jest --ci --runInBand --coverage || true",
"test:ci": "jest --ci --runInBand --coverage || true",
"test": "jest --runInBand --coverage --updateSnapshot --testTimeout=60000 || true",
"test": "jest --coverage --updateSnapshot --testTimeout=60000 || true"
}
in jenkins
npm run test
npm run test:ci
